# variable reference to object instance when multiple could exist

Tags: javascript, object, reference, controller

So I have a function call that manages some object creation. I narrowed my solution down to having a single controller object overseeing any number of any type of node objects that live on the passed elements. To allow for a rigid public API, I opted to use string identifiers to call into the controller object which will in turn manage the nodes appropriately. My issue is referencing that controller object after instantiation when I want to make method calls on it without needing it to live on every element alongside the nodes

```
$.fn.plugin = function(option) {
  var instance = null;

  if (typeof option === 'object' || !option) { // create new instance
    this.each(function() {
      if (!$.data(this, 'plugin-node')) { //check for existing nodes
        if (!instance) //create new controller if none found
          instance = new Plugin(this, option);

        $.data(this, 'plugin-node', nodeFactory(this, instance);
        // Use a factory to attach polymorphic objects to elements
      }
    });
  }

  else if (typeof option === 'string' && option in pubAPI) {
    // use instance as reference and call desired method on it
    // but instance will have been overwritten with null at this point
  }
}
```

I think that's all the info you need. Basically I need `instance` to not only be nothing when creating a new instance, but I need it to not be over written with `null` every time I make a method call via a string identifier. If it's a global variable then I can't have multiple instances at once, but if I have it within the functions scope like it is, then it's  overwritten with null every time I make any kind of call. Like I said, I don't want to have to attach it every element since I feel there's a solution using closures, but I just can't crack it. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see anything "overwriting `instance` with `null`" in the above. I would strongly advise not doing what's above, but not for that reason. (Plugins should almost never save state data for an entire set, which is what the above does; just per-element.)

Comment: We really can't help you without knowing more about why you need `Plugin` and separately `nodeFactory`, both of which seem to expect to access the element.

Comment: interesting, I was not aware of that practice. The overwriting happens after the plugins been instantiated and you have to call the function a second time with your string identifier. It would seem the easiest solution is to put that instance alongside my nodes and just grab it that way

Comment: It's not *overwritten*, it's a different `instance` variable entirely. The old one is still around, it's just not accessible to a subsequent call to `plugin` (it *would* be accessible to functions defined during the previous call). But you really want `data` here, so you store element-specific information.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I tried to keep it short and sweet to the problem I am having,  to much code in a question can be confusing I find. However I didn't even think of it being an entirely different variable. That would explain why I was having so much trouble. I would have thought closures allowed that to exist but I guess really there's no evidence to support that claim when I think about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This inside your `each` call:

```
instance = new Plugin(thias, option);
```

...suggests that `instance` is specific to an element. That being the case, it's declared in the wrong place, because `instance` (the variable) will be related to the entire *set* that the plugin was called on (and recreated even if the plugin is called a second time on the same set).

Plugins shouldn't behave like that. They should only save state on a per-element basis, which is exactly what jQuery's `data` is for.

I don't quite understand the `instance` vs. `nodes` thing in your code, but fundamentally, the structure I'd recommend would look like this:

```
$.fn.plugin = function(option) {

  if (typeof option === 'object' || !option) { // create new instance
    this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var pluginInformationForThisElement = $this.data('plugin-info');
      if (!pluginInformationForThisElement) {
        pluginInformationForThisElement = /*...set up the plugin information..*/;
        $this.data('plugin-node', pluginInformationForThisElement);
        // ...
      }
    });
  }

  else if (typeof option === 'string' && option in pubAPI) {
    // Use `$(this).data('plugin-information')` here to access the per-element
    // information...
  }
};
```

Comment: I'll b ehonest and realized I made a mistake. The `this` being based into `new Plugin` actually doesn't go anywhere, I am refactoring very heavily from the previous iteration in working on this concept. What really should be happening is only the `option` should be passed into the constructor. I'll make an edit to my question reflecting that as well as an extra bit to explain my concept behind the `instance` and `nodes`